# When should I unregister remoting channel?

Tags: c#, remoting

I have configure the channel by RemotingConfiguration.Configure(String, Boolean): Void.

On server side, it's hosted on a http server on a windows service.
And client side is a windows application.

The server is always waiting for a incoming call. So do I need to call ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(IChannel) : Void on some where?

And on client side, should I configure the Remoting Service on program run and Unregister on dispose? or would it better to register the channel on each request call?

Will the channel auto unregistered on my application exit on both client and server?
Thanks